# How to find correct executable with Sys.which on Windows

Tags: r, windows

What are the workarounds on Windows to make it so Sys.which finds the proper executables?  Two cases that are reoccuring problems:

1. `convert.exe` which is both a windows program and the ImageMagik program, but Sys.which only finds the windows one which is never wanted from R no matter how I seem to arrange things on my PATH.
2. `tar.exe` is packaged along with various things like git or mingw or whatever, and even when I have Rtools and Rbuildtools first in my path, the `tar` program from Rtools is never found, for example when installing a package from source.

So, I have resorted to writing a wrapper that calls 7-zip instead whenever I am on windows.  This can't be the thing to do can it?

#### Edit

Actually just adding an environment variable to `.Renviron`: `TAR=path/to/tar.exe` works fine for the `install.packages` example, and I am having trouble remembering where else the `tar.exe` was biting me, but Josh answered the main one, `convert.exe`.

Comment: This is one of the many reasons I stopped doing R development on Windows.

Comment: Can you provide an example of Sys.which() failing, e.g., in psuedocode `R.version.string; Sys.getenv("PATH")[c(1:3, CYGWIN_PATH_IDX)]; Sys.which("tar")`? Not that I'll be able to help, but in the interest of making your issue reproducible.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I asked a +/- identical question earlier this year [over on R-devel](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-devel/2015-May/071195.html). Among the replies was [this one](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-devel/2015-May/071199.html), by Henrik Bengtsson, who kindly provided the following useful function:

```
Sys.which2 <- function(cmd) {
    stopifnot(length(cmd) == 1)
    if (.Platform$OS.type == "windows") {
        suppressWarnings({
            pathname <- shell(sprintf("where %s 2> NUL", cmd), intern=TRUE)[1]
        })
        if (!is.na(pathname)) return(setNames(pathname, cmd))
    }
    Sys.which(cmd)
}

## Trying out Sys.which & Sys.which2 on my Windows box gives the following:
Sys.which("convert")
#                              convert 
# "C:\\Windows\\system32\\convert.exe" 
Sys.which2("convert")
#                                                 convert 
# "C:\\Program Files\\ImageMagick-6.8.8-Q16\\convert.exe"
```

I'm really not sure why R-core don't just fix `Sys.which()` to make it actually portable, but they at least do document root cause of this behavior in `?system` (whose functionality is afflicted by the same problem):

> The search path for 'command' may be system-dependent: it will
>   include the R 'bin' directory, the working directory and the
>   Windows system directories before 'PATH'.

Comment: FWIW, [here is the patch](https://github.com/pmur002/gridgraphics/commit/95beb6b8ada29f6543192d9b9a753c5980a33e42) I submitted to fix the problem this was causing in Paul Murrell's **gridGraphics** package. (That problem had been the genesis of the R-devel thread inked above.)

Answer (score 2):

Because `Sys.which()` is vectorized–and since I think that is useful–I've modified the Henrik Bengtsson code in the following function `sys_which()`, which should be a more robust and more similar version of `Sys.which()`:

```
## check if unix
is_unix <- function() grepl("unix", .Platform$OS.type, ignore.case = TRUE)

## robust version of Sys.which
sys_which <- function(x) {
  if (is_unix()) {
    return(Sys.which(x))
  }
  sys_win <- function(x) {
    if (grepl("\\S", path <- Sys.which(x))) {
      return(path)
    }
    path <- tryCatch(
      suppressWarnings(system(sprintf("where %s", x), intern = TRUE)[1]),
      warning = function(w) "",
      error = function(e) "")
    if (!grepl("\\S", path)) {
      return(`names<-`("", x))
    }
    `names<-`(path, x)
  }
  vapply(x, sys_win, character(1))
}
```

This has the following advantages:

1. **It's vectorized**–`sys_which()` can handle a vector (one *or more* input values) e.g., `sys_which(c("python", "python3"))`
2. **It's more error resistant**–use of `tryCatch(...)` ensures any inputs that result in an error from the system call get passed on to the normal `Sys.which()` function.

Example:

```
> sys_which(c("python", "python2.7", "python3", "asdf"))
#>            python                python2.7                  python3        asdf 
#> "/usr/bin/python"     "/usr/bin/python2.7" "/usr/local/bin/python3"          ""
```