# Why is R using system tar, not Rtools tar?

Tags: r, windows, windows-10

I'm trying to debug why I'm suddenly getting the error

> tar.exe: Error exit delayed from previous errors.

on running `install_github`. Thinking there might be a problem with the `tar` program, I came across this oddity:

```
> Sys.getenv("PATH")
[1] "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft SDKs\\Azure\\CLI2\\wbin;C:\\Rtools\\bin;C:\\Windows\\system32;[...]"

> Sys.which("tar")
                             tar 
"C:\\WINDOWS\\SYSTEM32\\tar.exe" 

> file.exists("C:\\Rtools\\bin\\tar.exe")
[1] TRUE
```

Why is R using the system `tar`, as opposed to the Rtools-supplied `tar`, when the Rtools directory is earlier in the path?

OS is Windows 10 2004 (build 19041.330), R 4.0.0.

Comment: Turns out the error was due to the repo containing a symlink, which causes problems on Windows

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This appears to be a known problem, for... several years now:

[How to find correct executable with Sys.which on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34030087/-/34031214)

I tried to find documentation for this. I came across this:

https://cran.r-project.org/manuals.html

and in turn this:

https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/fullrefman.pdf

but it turns out that PDF is specific to Unix, and omits Windows specific parts.
I am not sure of any official Windows PDF. So failing that, you can look at the
source directly:

> The search path for `command` may be system-dependent: it will include the
> `bin` directory, the working directory and the Windows system directories
> before `PATH`.

https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/92712b53/src/library/base/man/system.Rd#L77-L79

Note on the same page, I also see this:

> This interface has become rather complicated over the years: see `system2`
> for a more portable and flexible interface which is recommended for new code.

(If the Windows PDF is hosted in an official place, someone please let me know).

Comment: Ta. Looks like `Sys.which` (and `system`) behave like this because it's what the `SearchPath` Win32 function does: http://winapi.freetechsecrets.com/win32/WIN32SearchPath.htm